# getName() returns the old name of the file even if renameTo() has succeeded

Tags: java

I used the following code to rename a file and then get its new name:

```
File f1 = new File("C:/old.txt");
File f2 = new File("C:/new.txt");
System.out.println(f1.renameTo(f2));
System.out.println(f1.getName());
```

And the program returns

```
true
old.txt
```

renameTo() has succeeded, but why doesn't getName() return the new file name?

Comment: I believe its that you're using f1 in get name. Or you could try to use a string for f2

Comment: From the [`File` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) - *"Instances of the File class are immutable; that is, once created, the abstract pathname represented by a File object will never change"*

Comment: But if f1 has been renamed, why does getName() return the old name?

Comment: Search the site and there's bound to be a duplicate.

Comment: Because, as MadProgrammer said, file objects are *immutable* and **never** change.

Comment: `File` is a "abstract representation" of a file/path, it doesn't actually have to point to a valid file/path.  It represents the destination for other functionality, but until that functionality is executed, `File` can be anything.

Comment: Because the `File` class is misnamed. It represents a file *name*, including optional path, not the file itself.